# How drop still frames with timestamp ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, filter, motion

I have a ffmpeg command that allows me to drop duplicate frames and speed up the video and works well. I use it with hundreds of video recordings from a surveillance ip camera that does not have motion detection feature.

But, the files still have 1 frame per each second still because the video has a timestamp at the top, so I want to know if I could drop those still frames too somehow.

This is my current command:

```
ffmpeg -n -threads 2 -i input.mp4 -vf "mpdecimate,setpts=N/(25*TB)" -preset superfast -crf 30.0 -vcodec libx264 -movflags +faststart ouput.mp4
```

This is a sample screenshot showing the timestamp embedded on the video:
[image]
There is some way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you show screenshots of these frames - the two with only the changing timestamp and one before and after those ones?

Comment: I've added a screenshot, with the command above the video run fast, about one minute each 3 seconds (since the source video is near realtime and the command catchs up 25fps so I could se the seconds running realy fast when the image is still but there is no "jumps" in seconds or minutes... I want to add those "jumps" on those many minutes when the image is still and there is no motion. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use dvr-scan too (written in python) but I saw that it reencode the video and I dont trust much on that, I prefer to leave to ffmpeg the re-encoding task. It would be great if dvr-scan could export the timestamp in a ready to use format or even if I could use an image as a mask to mark which regions to watch and which to ignore. But to much hassle.